# If $G$ is a transitive permutation group then $\mathrm{fix}(G_\alpha)$ is a block

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I am new here and don't know much about Latex so, I attach my question from *Permutation Groups* by J. Dixon. I hope to get a help for it:

**1.6.5** Let $G$ be a transitive subgroup of $\mathrm{Sym}(\Omega)$ and let $\alpha \in \Omega$. Show that $\mathrm{fix}(G_\alpha)$ is a block for $G$. In particular, if $G$ is primitive, then either $\mathrm{fix}(G_\alpha)=\{\alpha\}$ or else $G_\alpha=1$ and $G$ has prime degree.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the meaning of a block for a permutation group? If you prove $fix(G_\alpha)$ is a block for $G$ then Primitivity of $G$ makes the block to be trivial.

Comment: I believe a _block_ is a $B \subset \Omega$ such that for $x \in G$ either $xB = B$ or $xB \cap B = \varnothing$.

Comment: A block "B" is a subset of "Omega" which for any "g in G", "B^g=B" or "B^g has no intersection with B but empty".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A transitive permutation action comes from $G$ acting via right multiplication on $H=G_\alpha$.  The fixed points $B=fix(G_\alpha)$ of $G_\alpha$ correspond to cosets of $H$ in $N_G(H)$.  Saying that $g\in G$ is such that $gB\cap B\neq\emptyset$ is essentially the same as saying $(\alpha)g\in B$. This means $Hg\subset N_G(H)$, so that $g\in N_G(H)$;  $g$ thus permutes the cosets of $H$ in $N_G(H)$, that is, fixes $B$ setwise.

Comment: Thanks so much for neat answer.